# PostgreSQL 9.4 UPDATE...FROM error with REGEX operators

Tags: regex, postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.4

I'm trying to use a regex pattern matching with PostgreSQL 9.4:

Have looked through previous answers but nothing I can find matches this particular problem

`select 'apple' ~ '^.*pp.*$'` returns 't' as expected

`update <table> set column = 'value' where name ~* '^.*pp.*$'` also works.

But:

`update <table> set column = 'value' from <other_table> where name ~* '^.*pp.*$'` produces an error:

The specific example:

```
update 
  members set 
    pattern = a.pattern 
  from 
    services a 
  where
    organisation ~* '^.*' || replace(a.pattern, ' ', '.*') || '.*$';
```

*ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text
LINE 1: ...attern = a.pattern from services a where organisati...*

It seems the where clause after the FROM table in the update is not recognising or processing the regex operator correctly.
Or, equally probably, I'm misunderstanding the UPDATE...FROM syntax

Many thanks if you can help

Answer (score 1):

you are missing brackets around string expressions. These operators (`~` and `||`) has same priority and then are evaluated from left.

```
postgres=# update foo set b = a where a ~ 'ab';
UPDATE 1
postgres=# update foo set b = a where a ~ 'ab' || 'xxxx';
ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text
LINE 1: update foo set b = a where a ~ 'ab' || 'xxxx';
                                   ^
postgres=# update foo set b = a where a ~ ('ab' || 'xxxx');
UPDATE 0
```

Comment: Excellent.  Many thanks.  I had tried parentheses before but around the whole where clause ie  where (organisation...)